# C# asp.net alt tag issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Hi all im new to the site and have a question to do with c# in asp.net. i have made a website using HTML5 markup and CSS in asp.net with c# for the code behind. The issue im having is i made a index.aspx page with c# code behind to show all my products in a panel which are retrieved directly from the image folder using the Fillpage method. The problem i have is im not sure how to add alt tags to the images as i don't actually see the images until i run my site in the browser. I tested my site for accessibility and it showed the missing alt tag error. Can anyone give me some advice on how to add the alt tags to the images please?
Thank you.
index.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    public partial class Index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Fillpage();
    }
    private void Fillpage()
    {

        //Retrieve list of all products in the database
        ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel();
        List<Product> products = productModel.GetAllProducts();

        //check products exist in the database
        if (products !=null)
        {
        //create a new panel with an imagebutton and 2 labels for each         product
            foreach (Product product in products)
            {
                Panel productPanel = new Panel();
                ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton();
                Label lblName = new Label();
                Label lblPrice = new Label();

                //Set childControls properties
                imageButton.ImageUrl = "~/Images/Products/" + product.Image;
                imageButton.CssClass = "productImage";
                imageButton.PostBackUrl = "~/pages/Product.aspx?id=" + product.ID;

                lblName.Text = product.Name;
                lblName.CssClass = "productName";
                lblPrice.Text = "£" + product.Price;
                lblPrice.CssClass = "productPrice";

                //Add childControls to the panel
                productPanel.Controls.Add(imageButton);
                productPanel.Controls.Add(new Literal{Text = "<br />"});
                productPanel.Controls.Add(lblName);
                productPanel.Controls.Add(new Literal{Text = "<br />"});
                productPanel.Controls.Add(lblPrice);

                //Add dynamic paneld to static parent panel
                pnlProducts.Controls.Add(productPanel);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //no products found
            pnlProducts.Controls.Add(new Literal {Text = "No Products found!"});
        }
        }
    }
    product.aspx.cs

    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

    public partial class Pages_Product : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FillPage();
    }

    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["id"]))
        {
            string clientId = Context.User.Identity.GetUserId();

            if (clientId != null)
            {
                int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
                int amount = Convert.ToInt32(ddlAmount.SelectedValue);

                Cart cart = new Cart
                {
                    Amount = amount,
                    ClientID = clientId,
                    DatePurchased = DateTime.Now,
                    IsInCart = true,
                    ProductID = id
                };

                CartModel model = new CartModel();
                lblResult.Text = model.InsertCart(cart);
            }
            else
            {
                lblResult.Text = " Please log in to order products ";
            }
        }
    }

    private void FillPage()
    {
        //Get selected product data
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["id"]))
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
            ProductModel model = new ProductModel();
            Product product = model.GetProduct(id);

            //Fill page with data
            lblTitle.Text = product.Name;
            lblDescription.Text = product.Description;
            lblPrice.Text = "Price per unit:<br/>£ " + product.Price;
            imgProduct.ImageUrl = "~/Images/Products/" + product.Image;
            lblItemNr.Text = product.ID.ToString();

            //Fill amount list with numbers 1-20
            int[] amount = Enumerable.Range(1, 20).ToArray();
            ddlAmount.DataSource = amount;
            ddlAmount.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
            ddlAmount.DataBind();
        }
        }

    }
```

Comment: You should really provide code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `imageButton.AlternateText` property.

Comment: So i would  add this to my child control properties. i.e. imageButton.Alternate Text=" ";  but i don't understand what to enter between the quotes? i have 13 different images. would this just give an alt attribute for all images?

Comment: No. This always will be an alt text specific to an instance of your `ImageButton`. In your case you build `ImageButton` in `foreach` loop, so if you do `imageButton.AlternateText = product.Name;`, then you'll see the result.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Please could you give me an example of where to put the for loop? and how it should look.

Comment: Right after `imageButton.PostBackUrl = "~/pages/Product.aspx?id=" + product.ID;`